# Testing a (new) firewall

Tags: firewall, lan, gateway

I have a small home-LAN. I want to install a gateway PC running my own firewall/DNS/DHCP/VPN/etc. I plan to run either pfSense, OPNsense, IPfire or Debian 8. I'm not sure which, so I want to do some testing first.

**Current State**:

`Internet --- [ISP modem] ----------------- switch --- (LAN)`
The ISP modem has NAT/firewall functionality.

**Future State**:

`Internet --- [ISP modem] --- {gateway} --- switch --- (LAN)`
The ISP modem will be put in bridge mode. NAT/firewall/etc functionality will be migrated to the new gateway.

How can I (temporarily) set things up, before implementing the future state, so that I can test the various options while the current state network remains operational for my family and without risk of "de-firewalling" the existing network?

*Note*: The `switch` is managed, maybe that could help?

Comment: Because you want to change the modem configuration, you cannot.

Comment: @DanielB :  Can I *before* I change the modem configuration?

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect that I want to know how to modify the *current state* to be able to test the various OSs/configurations on the gateway PC *before* implementing the future state. If I just connect it to the LAN I cannot see how to test it as a firewall/gateway.